# SQL - first in first out

Tags: sql, fifo

I want to implement FIFO in my stock table

table looks like:

```
---+------------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------
id | shift_type | item_type | amount | name         | date
---+------------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------
1  | in         | apple     | 50     | apple type 1 | 2017-12-01
2  | out        | apple     | 30     | apple type 1 | 2017-12-02
3  | in         | apple     | 40     | apple type 2 | 2017-12-04
4  | in         | apple     | 60     | apple type 3 | 2017-12-05
5  | out        | apple     | 20     | apple type 1 | 2017-12-07
6  | out        | apple     | 10     | apple type 1 | 2017-12-07
7  | in         | apple     | 20     | apple type 3 | 2017-12-09
```

and it keeps info about stock shifts.
If I want to take just the oldest incomes - I can take records with lowest id or oldest date.

But... there are also "out" shifts.
So if I want to take for example 50 apples, query should return me 2 records:

```
---+------------+-----------+--------+--------------+------------+-----
id | shift_type | item_type | amount | name         | date       | take
---+------------+-----------+--------+--------------+------------+-----
1  | in         | apple     | 50     | apple type 1 | 2017-12-01 | 20
3  | in         | apple     | 40     | apple type 2 | 2017-12-04 | 30
```

because - first out(id 2) takes 30 apples, so there is 20 left from income id 1, and rest of it should be taken from income id 3

How can I implement it with SQL?

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation with some examples. Your explanation is not clear and what is the actual requirement?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What does "take 50 apples" mean? Is 50 an input to the required query? Why not just take all 50 from record 1?

Comment: In this example I have 110 apples in stock and I want to take 50, but I can't take it from record 1, because in record 2 i've taken 30, so there is only 2 from record 1 and I have to take another 30 from record 3 :)

Comment: So is it like, say I need some 50 apples on date 12/04? because if you want to take just 50 you can take from the first record itself since it is available

Comment: If you have the system where "in" and "out" are the only (and mandatory) event types then I would suggest you to make those columns, not rows. It will be much easier to operate on that kind of structure both for you and your DBMS

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

I did something here. But need to test with different inputs.

Given a no, say 50 in the outer select query it will give you list of stacks that you need to take apples from.

```
WITH view_t
AS (
SELECT 1 id
    ,'in' shift_type
    ,'apple' item_type
    ,50 amount
    ,'apple type 1' NAME
    ,TO_DATE('2017-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') date1
FROM dual

UNION ALL

SELECT 2
    ,'out'
    ,'apple'
    ,30
    ,'apple type 1'
    ,TO_DATE('2017-12-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
FROM dual

UNION ALL

SELECT 3
    ,'in'
    ,'apple'
    ,40
    ,'apple type 2'
    ,TO_DATE('2017-12-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
FROM dual

UNION ALL

SELECT 4
    ,'in'
    ,'apple'
    ,60
    ,'apple type 3'
    ,TO_DATE('2017-12-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
FROM dual

UNION ALL

SELECT 5
    ,'out'
    ,'apple'
    ,30
    ,'apple type 2'
    ,TO_DATE('2017-12-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
FROM dual
)
SELECT id
,date1
,shift_type
,NAME
,itemrem
,nvl((
        50 - LAG(itemrem) OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            )
        ), itemrem) take
 FROM (
SELECT id
    ,date1
    ,shift_type
    ,NAME
    ,SUM(amtretain) OVER (
        ORDER BY id
        ) itemrem
FROM (
    SELECT id
        ,date1
        ,shift_type
        ,amount
        ,signamt
        ,NAME
        ,CASE 
            WHEN LEAD(shift_type) OVER (
                    ORDER BY id
                    ) = 'out'
                THEN LEAD(signamt) OVER (
                        ORDER BY id
                        ) + signamt
            ELSE signamt
            END amtretain
    --date1,shift_type,sum(signamt) over(order by id)
    FROM (
        SELECT id
            ,shift_type
            ,NAME
            ,item_type
            ,date1
            ,DECODE(shift_type, 'in', amount, 'out', amount * - 1) signamt
            ,amount
        FROM view_t
        )
    )
WHERE shift_type = 'in'
);
```

The idea behind the approach is to,

1. convert the signs of the amount based on the shift_type
2. Use lead to subtract the signamt based on its shift type
3. Use a running total to identify the remaining apples at each date
4. Finally using LAG with the input no of apples to calculate how much to take